# C# Autofac Generic interface resolve to instance of base class instead of child

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

First, some background on my code.

I have a interface for items that can be saved/used with a data store/repository type service:

```
public interface IItem
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

```
public interface IDataStore<T> where T: IItem { ... }
```

An example of such an item:

```
public class ItemNormalExample : IItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string RandomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then I also have special/specific type of item, which other items inherit from. This is where my problem lies.

```
public interface ISpecialItem : IItem
{
    string ImportantString { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ItemSpecialBase : ISpecialItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ImportantString  { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ItemSpecialExample : ItemSpecialBase 
{
    public string RandomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Autofac to resolve instances of this data store of each concrete implementation of `IItem`s. I.e.:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataStore<ItemNormalExample>>().As<IDataStore<ItemNormalExample>>();
```

This works as intended, however, for my objects inheriting from the `ItemSpecialBase` base class, I would like these to be instantiated as a DataStore of the base class type instead of the actual child class.

Something like this (This doesn't work):

```
builder.RegisterType<DataStore<ItemSpecialBase>>().As<IDataStore<ItemSpecialExample>>();
```

My intend is for every object inheriting from `ItemSpecialBase` to use the same DataStore. My DataStore class supports this and works fine.

How can I accomplish this using Autofac?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have run into a [Variant Generic Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) problem!

Specifically, when you do...

```cs
builder
  .RegisterType<DataStore<ItemSpecialBase>>()
  .As<IDataStore<ItemSpecialExample>>();
```

...you're attempting to cast a `Storage<Base>` into an `IStorage<Child>`, which is known as *Contravariance*.

The Contravariance problem can be simplified as so:

```cs
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }

interface IStorage<T> {
    void Put(T thing);
    T? Get();
}
class Storage<T> : IStorage<T> {
    public void Put(T t) { }
    public T? Get() { return default(T); }
}

void Main() {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // What you're attempting to do:
    builder.RegisterType<Storage<Animal>>().As<IStorage<Cat>>();
    builder.Build();

    // Is equivalent to this:
    IStorage<Cat> cats = new Storage<Animal>();

    // The compiler will stop you from doing either.
}
```

The problem is that generics are validated at *compile-time*. And the compiler notices that, while you can `Put` a Cat `in` an Animal Storage, when you try to `Get` something `out` of storage **it *cannot guarantee* you'll get a Cat - the storage may contain Dogs**. (note the `in` and `out`, which are relevant to the covariant/contravariant discussion).

One thing you can do is to acknowledge to the compiler that you will only attempt to put a Child class `in`, and will not try to get a Child out:

```cs
// Notice the `in` constraint
interface IStorage<in T> {
    // We can pass `T` in as parameter
    void Put(T thing);
    
    // We cannot return `T` anymore, because we promised to
    // only use T in the `in` direction, and not out.
    object? Get();
}

// This stays the same. `in` can only be enforced against interfaces.
class Storage<T> : IStorage<T> {
    public void Put(T t) { }
    public object? Get() { return default(T); }
}

void Main() {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // This is now allowed:
    builder.RegisterType<Storage<Animal>>().As<IStorage<Cat>>();
    builder.Build();
    
    // And this too:
    IStorage<Cat> cats = new Storage<Animal>();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! this seems exactly what I was intending. I'm relatively new to OOP so theres still alot of lingo and patterns I don't know..

Comment: @XiangZhou, yeah generics kinda opens up a whole can of worms in terms of polymorphism. Don't be surprised when one day, you'll run into another problem with it and the only answer you get is simply "you can't do it with generics".